# Node.js setInterval and nextTick inaccurate for second invocation

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer

Let me preface this by saying that **I am fully aware that the timers in JS are not accurate**. This is not the point here. I am interested in the reasons for the following behavior more due to curiosity.

I am scheduling a function via `setInterval` or `setTimeout` to run every x ms. I also measure the time that actually elapsed time on a ms accuracy. This is the code:

```
var counter = 0;
var start = Date.now();
var last = start;
var now;
var step = 10;

var tick = function () {
    now = Date.now();
    console.log(counter++, now, now - last);
    last = now;

    if (counter > 10) {
        clearInterval(tick);
    }
};

setInterval(tick, step);
```

The output with Node.js 4.0.0 on Ubuntu 15.04 (3.19.0-15-generic) is the following:

```
0 1442445968559 11
1 1442445968597 38
2 1442445968611 14
3 1442445968621 10
4 1442445968632 11
5 1442445968641 9
6 1442445968651 10
7 1442445968661 10
8 1442445968672 11
9 1442445968683 11
```

I can see the inaccuracy of 1 to 2 ms of the majority of calls. The interesting one is the second line which is off by 28 ms.

The same experiment with a delay of 100 ms:

```
0 1442446176790 100
1 1442446176940 150
2 1442446177044 104
3 1442446177145 101
4 1442446177245 100
5 1442446177345 100
6 1442446177446 101
7 1442446177546 100
8 1442446177646 100
9 1442446177747 101
```

Again, the second line stands out.

A more accurate version can be built by using `process.nextTick`:

```
var counter = 0;
var start = Date.now();
var last = start;
var now;
var step = 10;

var check = function () {
    now = Date.now();
    if (now >= last + step) {
        tick();
    }
    if (counter < 10) {
        process.nextTick(check);
    }
};

var tick = function () {
    console.log(counter++, now, now - last);
    last = now;
};

process.nextTick(check);
```

The result is:

```
0 1442446399599 10
1 1442446399620 21
2 1442446399630 10
3 1442446399640 10
4 1442446399650 10
5 1442446399660 10
6 1442446399670 10
7 1442446399680 10
8 1442446399690 10
9 1442446399700 10
```

Now all but the second call are perfect.

Can anybody explain why? I imagine this is something that has to be dealt with on system level.

Comment: My first guess would be some startup work node has to perform, before running in regular mode. Have you tried running your code after, say, 1s of warmup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the `console.log()`. The second action will take longer due to `console.log` taking more cpu time during the first call. (warning: this is an educated guess)

```
var counter = 0;
var start = Date.now();
var last = start;
var now;
var step = 10;
var data = [];
var tick = function () {
    now = Date.now();
    var time = now - last;
    last = now;
    counter++;
    data.push(counter + " " + now +" "+time);

    if (counter > 10) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        console.log(data.join('\n'));
    }
};

var interval = setInterval(tick, step);
```

results:

```
1 1442450286606 12
2 1442450286617 11
3 1442450286627 10
4 1442450286637 10
5 1442450286648 11
6 1442450286658 10
7 1442450286668 10
8 1442450286678 10
9 1442450286688 10
10 1442450286698 10
11 1442450286708 10
```

Edit - A modification of the above with cpu processing gives a little extra weight to my hypothesis.

```
var counter = 0;
var start = Date.now();
var last = start;
var now;
var step = 10;
var data = [];
var tick = function () {
    now = Date.now();
    var time = now - last;
    last = now;
    counter++;
    data.push(counter + " " + now +" "+time);
    if (counter == 4){
      for (var i=0;i<10000000;i++){
        //waste some time
      }
    }

    if (counter > 10) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        console.log(data.join('\n'));
    }
};

var interval = setInterval(tick, step);
```

results show an increase in time after making the cpu more busy:

```
1 1442451041828 12
2 1442451041838 10
3 1442451041849 11
4 1442451041860 11
5 1442451041902 42
6 1442451041914 12
7 1442451041924 10
8 1442451041934 10
9 1442451041944 10
10 1442451041954 10
11 1442451041964 10
```